# Problem with format of List of Figures and List of Tables

Tags: indexing

I have a problem with the format of my LoF and LoT. The numbers of the figures and tables in the lists are supperposed. I don't want this results, but my level in LaTeX isn't really good.

The preamble is right here. I don't have all code, because is too long to explain here.

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% get a copy of \protected@write
\let\protected@iwrite\protected@write
% patch the copy to add \immediate
\xpatchcmd{\protected@iwrite}{\write}{\immediate\write}{}{}
% patch \addsymline to use \protected@iwrite instead of \immediate\write
\xpatchcmd{\addsymline}
{\immediate\write#5}
{\protected@iwrite{#5}{}}
{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{notoccite}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}

\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEETRAN-SPA}

\usepackage[format=hang,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[display] % shape
{\vspace{-2cm} \centering \bfseries\huge} % format
{} % label
{0cm} % sep
{\centering} % before-code
[\centering] % after-code

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% redefinition of the plain style:
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage[final]{listofsymbols} % cambiar por final en el definitivo
{\renewcommand{\symheading}{\chapter*{Lista de Símbolos}} 
    
\parindent=0mm

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makenoidxglossaries
\input{acronimo.tex}
\input{glosario.tex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all, %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}
```

Adding my problem with this image.
Thanks for your help!

[image: Problem with numbers of figures and tables!]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your example is not compilable, it's a fragment only, but use `tocloft` and change the `\cftchapnumwidth` etc. lengths

Comment: Sorry Christian Hupfer, but my code really is long, so I have to split in different files.

Comment: Your code is too long for TeX.SE. Reduce it to the minimal compilable version that still has this issue

Comment: Since you load `titlesec` you also can use `titletoc`.